# HTML rendered in a Grails template does not get attached to the page source(DOM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, grails-2.0

I have multiple tabs in my page and a single empty div below the tabs. I'm loading different grails templates into this div like the following

```
$('.project-content').load('<g:createLink controller="test" action="testDashboard" params="    [testInstance:applicationInstance.name]" />' + "/" + new Date().getTime() );
```

My controller handles this as follows:

```
def testDashboard(){
        render template: 'testing/testTemplate', model: [applicationInstance:          params.get('applicationInstance')],contentType: 'html'
    }
```

The template itself has some html content within a div

Content to be displayed

The template does get rendered inside the div. However when i view the source for the page I cant find the template html source.

Can you please tell me how i can make this available? I need it to attach some events to testDiv

Thanks,

Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never find it in the html Source-Code because it isnt there.
Your Js that "loads" the templates is executed **after** the document (document==Sourcecode) is loaded. So You are manipulating the DOM by loading new content to it, to see it, just use the element-inspector of chrome or firebug for firefox.

If you want to attach events to the content, you have to delegate the selectors or you pass the relevant script to execute within the template, thats also possible.It will execute as soon as your template is successfully loaded.